# creating docker container on Linux from Jenkins running on windows

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins

I have a build pipeline running on Windows that I cannot move to Linux, the simple reason being that it uses SQL Server tools not currently available on the RC1 version of SQL Server on Linux. Therefore my only option for running my build pipeline which needs to spin up SQL Server in containers on a Linux machine is to keep Jenkins on windows. My question is this, what is the most elegant way of creating a container on a remote Linux host from a windows server ?. I could use remote shells, however this seems like a really clunky way of doing things.

Comment: Can't you use Jenkins (given Jenkins is installed on the windows host) to perform this task? Install a slave in Linux host and execute a job on it to bring up the SQL Instance in it.

Comment: This would work for spinning up the container, however I would still have to call sqlpackage from the windows machine, is it possible with Jenkins to have part of the build pipeline performed by the master and then part by the slave ?

Comment: Are you using Pipeline job with a Jenkins file?

Comment: Yes I am using a pipeline job with a Jenkins file

Comment: Yes, it is possible to run few steps in master and another few steps in slaves. You can do something like this: 

`node('master') {
  ...................
}
node('slave1 && slave2') {
  ....................
}`

Comment: Anil, If you give me this information in the form of an answer, I will mark my question as answered and upvote you. Unfortunately I cannot do this via comments.

Comment: Posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by installing a `slave` of the Jenkins (that is installed in `Windows` host) on your `Linux` machine and execute a job which will bring up a SQL container.

Since you are using a `Pipeline` job and want to execute few steps in the master and then call the SQL packages in remote hosts from your `Windows` host you can follow the below syntax to achieve that in a single pipeline job:

```
node('master') { 
................... 
<some task to perform>
...................
} 
node('slave1 && slave2') { 
...................
<some task to perform>
...................
}
```